# xarray groupby: Apply different reducers to variables

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I'm using `xarray`'s `groupby` + reducer to perform spatial overlay/aggregation on spatial rasters. I'm wondering if there is a way to use a different reducer for certain data variables. In the code below for instance, I would like `categorical_variable` to be reduced with `first()` (or `mode` but that doesn't seem to be implemented), and `continuous_variable` to be reduced with `mean()`

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

categorical_variable = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],
                                 [1,1,1,1,2],
                                 [1,1,1,2,2],
                                 [1,1,2,2,2],
                                 [1,2,2,2,2]], dtype='int16')
grouping_variable = np.array([[1,1,1,2,2],
                              [1,1,3,2,2],
                              [1,3,3,3,3],
                              [3,3,3,3,3],
                              [4,4,4,4,4]], dtype='int16')
continuous_variable = np.random.rand(5,5)
xr_dataset = xr.Dataset({'grouping_variable': xr.DataArray(grouping_variable,
                                                           dims=['x', 'y']),
                         'categorical_variable': xr.DataArray(categorical_variable,
                                                              dims=['x', 'y']),
                         'continuous_variable': xr.DataArray(continuous_variable,
                                                             dims=['x', 'y'])})
xr_grouped = xr_dataset.groupby('grouping_variable')
xr_reduced = xr_grouped.mean()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in one go in xarray currently AFAIK, but since you're losing the spatial structure anyway you can go via pandas quite simply and use `agg`:

```
>>> df = xr_dataset.to_dataframe()
>>> df.groupby('grouping_variable').agg({"categorical_variable": "first",
                                         "continuous_variable": "mean"})

                   categorical_variable  continuous_variable
grouping_variable                                           
1                                     1             0.458534
2                                     1             0.822294
3                                     1             0.539483
4                                     1             0.515586
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance is not optimal but this is what I ended up doing:

```
xr_dataset = xr.merge([
  xr_dataset.categorical_variable.groupby('grouping_variable').first(),
  xr_dataset.continuous_variable.groupby('grouping_variable').mean(),
  ...
])
```